# Lenovo B570e WiFi is not working on 11.04

Tags: 11.04, wireless, kernel

Can any body tell me how to start my WiFi? It is not working with 11.04. I am new to Ubuntu. Please any body give me the code to compile and how it will work. I am really stuck with this problem.

My laptop model is Lenovo B570e. Please help me out.

Comment: If you are new to Ubuntu, then why do you install an old version? ``12.04`` is the current release, ``11.04`` may not support your hardware properly. Also, please don't tag your question with unrelated topics.

Comment: [Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04 and try it again.

Comment: Also, please do not use caps within your title, or unrelated tags. It may discourage users who have a solution, or cause organization issues if tags are misused.

Comment: 11.04 is going to be End of Life by the end of this month, anyways, so 12.04 is a better version to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Lenovo v570 and I had the same problem. Perhaps what worked for me will work for you.

Try this: `sudo rmmod -f acer-wmi`

Once that's done your wifi should just kick on, if that is the cause of the problem. If that does work, you can make that permanent by creating a blacklist for it:

`sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf`

Then use nano or vi/vim to open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf` and write this line to that file: `blacklist acer-wmi`. That will keep that module from loading when you start your computer.

Again, this is what worked for me when I had that problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: bro i am asking for lenovo not for acer to do this the architecture are complete different any how thanks for your reply